# Recommended layover in BKK (from USM to FRA)?

Tags: layovers, bangkok, bkk

I will be going with Bangkok Airways from Koh Samui (USM) to Bangkok (BKK), where I will switch to Lufthansa to Frankfurt (FRA).

I assume I can check through my luggage in Koh Samui. Is then 2 hours between arrival and departure enough or would you recommend more layover in BKK?

Answer (score 3):

If both flights are on the same ticket (single booking), than this should be no problem. Bangkok Airways has an interline agreement with Lufthansa from USM. Minimum connection time in BKK is 75 minutes.

See http://www.bangkokair.com/pages/view/check-in-through

If it's on two separate tickets, than all bets are off and this is unlikely to work.